# DropDown saving correct values

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I want to save the value from the dropdown but it's just staying at the original value? and is the more efficient way of doing the true to false i have seen ? floaitng about in terms of decissions.

```
user _currentUser;
    DBContext _db = new DBContext();

      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            UserValidationResult userStatus = (UserValidationResult)Session["userStatus"];


            user query = _db.GetCurrentUser(userStatus.User.UserId);


            dpstatus.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(query.isEnabled);
        }
    }


      protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

          UserValidationResult userStatus = (UserValidationResult)Session["userStatus"];


          user query = _db.GetCurrentUser(userStatus.User.UserId);

          if (dpstatus.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
              query.isEnabled = true;
          else
              query.isEnabled = false;

          _db.SaveChanges();

      }
```

Edit to show html markup

```
<h1>User Status </h1>       

        <div class="login-fields">

            Status <asp:DropDownList ID="dpstatus" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Enabled</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">Disabled</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>


                  <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="button btn btn-success btn-large" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />

            </div>
```

Comment: It's staying the original value in the database? Or in the selected item in the drop down?

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML mark-up that shows the drop down please

Comment: @CodeUniquely i added the markup above please see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see an issue here:

```
dpstatus.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(query.isEnabled);
```

SelectedIndex refers to the index of the list items in the dropdownlist not the value of the item.  I think what you intend to do is select the item based on the value, like so:

```
dpstatus.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(query.isEnabled).ToString();
```

Comment: @Mag while this was the answer i was setting the guid to query string insteasd of the current user thanks anyway